# Plotly python regression in ternary space

Tags: python, plotly, regression, trendline

I'm trying to draw a regression line in plotly python in ternary space, but there doesn't seem to be an option like "trendline = 'loess' for scatter ternaries. Is there another way to achieve the same result for ternaries? Code from a previous post that makes a spline line but not a regression.

```
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objects as go

a = np.array([0.15, 0.15, 0.17, 0.2 , 0.21, 0.24, 0.26, 0.27, 0.27, 0.29, 0.32, 0.35, 0.39, 0.4 , 0.4 , 0.41, 0.47, 0.48, 0.51, 0.52, 0.54, 0.56, 0.59, 0.62, 0.63, 0.65, 0.69, 0.73, 0.74])
b = np.array([0.14, 0.15, 0.1 , 0.17, 0.17, 0.18, 0.05, 0.16, 0.17, 0.04, 0.03, 0.14, 0.13, 0.13, 0.14, 0.14, 0.13, 0.13, 0.14, 0.14, 0.15, 0.16, 0.18, 0.2 , 0.21, 0.22, 0.24, 0.25, 0.25])
c = np.array([0.71, 0.7 , 0.73, 0.63, 0.62, 0.58, 0.69, 0.57, 0.56, 0.67, 0.65, 0.51, 0.48, 0.47, 0.46, 0.45, 0.4 , 0.39, 0.35, 0.34, 0.31, 0.28, 0.23, 0.18, 0.16, 0.13, 0.07, 0.02, 0.01])

fig = go.Figure()

curve_portion = np.where((b < 0.15) & (c > 0.6))
curve_other_portion = np.where(~((b < 0.15) & (c > 0.6)))

def add_plot_spline_portions(fig, indices_groupings):
    for indices in indices_groupings:
        fig.add_trace(go.Scatterternary({
            'mode': 'lines',
            'connectgaps': True,
            'a': a[indices],
            'b': b[indices],
            'c': c[indices],
            'line': {'color': 'black', 'shape': 'spline', 'smoothing': 1},
            'marker': {'size': 2, 'line': {'width': 0.1}}
            })
            )    

add_plot_spline_portions(fig, [curve_portion, curve_other_portion])
fig.show(renderer='png')
```

[image: jagged spline rather than regression]

Answer (score 0):

I can outline what I think is a general sort of solution - it doesn't have as much mathematical rigor as I would like, and involves some guess and check type work - but hopefully it's helpful.

The first consideration is that for this regression on a ternary plot, there are only two degrees of freedom because `A+B+C=1` (you might find [this explanation](https://www.researchgate.net/post/Can_anyone_help_with_the_determination_of_ternary_regression_equation) helpful). This means it only makes sense to consider the relationship between two of the variables at a time. What we really want to do is create a regression between two of the variables, then determine the value of the third variable using the equation A+B+C=1.

The second consideration is bit harder to define, but since you are after a regression that captures the "reversing" nature of the variable `A`, we want a regression where A can take on repeated values. I think the most straightforward way to achieve this is for A to be the variable you are predicting.

For simplicity sake, let's say we use a degree 2 polynomial regression that predicts A from either B or C. We can make a scatter and choose whichever polynomial will have a better fit for our purposes.

Here is a quick eda:

```
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

a = np.array([0.15, 0.15, 0.17, 0.2 , 0.21, 0.24, 0.26, 0.27, 0.27, 0.29, 0.32, 0.35, 0.39, 0.4 , 0.4 , 0.41, 0.47, 0.48, 0.51, 0.52, 0.54, 0.56, 0.59, 0.62, 0.63, 0.65, 0.69, 0.73, 0.74])
b = np.array([0.14, 0.15, 0.1 , 0.17, 0.17, 0.18, 0.05, 0.16, 0.17, 0.04, 0.03, 0.14, 0.13, 0.13, 0.14, 0.14, 0.13, 0.13, 0.14, 0.14, 0.15, 0.16, 0.18, 0.2 , 0.21, 0.22, 0.24, 0.25, 0.25])
c = np.array([0.71, 0.7 , 0.73, 0.63, 0.62, 0.58, 0.69, 0.57, 0.56, 0.67, 0.65, 0.51, 0.48, 0.47, 0.46, 0.45, 0.4 , 0.39, 0.35, 0.34, 0.31, 0.28, 0.23, 0.18, 0.16, 0.13, 0.07, 0.02, 0.01])

## eda to determine polynomial of best fit to predict A 
fig_eda = make_subplots(rows=1, cols=2)

fig_eda.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=b, y=a, mode='markers'),row=1, col=1)
coefficients = np.polyfit(b,a,2)
p = np.poly1d(coefficients)
b_vals = np.linspace(min(b),max(b))
a_pred = np.array([p(x) for x in b_vals])
fig_eda.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=b_vals, y=a_pred, mode='lines'),row=1, col=1)

fig_eda.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=c, y=a, mode='markers'),row=1, col=2)
coefficients = np.polyfit(c,a,2)
p = np.poly1d(coefficients)
c_vals = np.linspace(min(c),max(c))
a_pred = np.array([p(x) for x in c_vals])
fig_eda.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=c_vals, y=a_pred, mode='lines'),row=1, col=2)
```

[image]

Notice how `predicting A from B` looks like it captures the reversing nature of A better than predicting A from C. If we try to make a degree 2 polynomial regression on A from C, we can see A is not going to repeat within the domain of C: [0,1] because of the very low sloping nature of that polynomial.

So let's proceed with this regression with C as the predictor variable, and A as the predicted variable (and B also being a predicted variable using `B = 1 - (A + C)`.

```
fig = go.Figure()

fig.add_trace(go.Scatterternary({
    'mode': 'markers',
    'connectgaps': True,
    'a': a,
    'b': b,
    'c': c
}))   

## since A+B+C = 100, we only need to fit a polynomial between two of the variables
## fit an n-degree polynomial to 2 of your variables
## source https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.polyfit.html

coefficients = np.polyfit(b,a,2)
p = np.poly1d(coefficients)

## we use the entire domain of the input variable B
b_vals = np.linspace(0,1)

a_pred = np.array([p(x) for x in b_vals])
c_pred = 1 - (b_vals + a_pred)

fig.add_trace(go.Scatterternary({
    'mode': 'lines',
    'connectgaps': True,
    'a': a_pred,
    'b': b_vals,
    'c': c_pred,
    'marker': {'size': 2, 'color':'red', 'line': {'width': 0.1}}
}))   

fig.show()
```

[image]

This is the lowest degree polynomial regression that allows for repeated values of A (a linear regression to predict A would be the wouldn't allow A to take on repeated values). However, you can definitely experiment with increasing the degree of the polynomial you are using, and predicting A from either variables B or C.

Comment: I think your example is on the right track. polyfit takes the whole layout of points and draws a line accordingly, but the meaning of the reverse checkmark is lost in the process. I was just thinking that a combination of the answer you gave in my previous post and this one would probably do the trick... not sure. Perhaps performing the regression in much smaller triangles, iteratively(?), and adding them together to form a continuous line is the best answer. I'm going to try and combine your previous answer with this one and see how it goes.

Comment: @Benjamin thanks for the feedback - you're right that by trying to regress to all of the points at once, it can be difficult to capture specific behavior - maybe not even possible if there is more than one pattern that needs to be captured. if your priority is getting a smooth curve to go through most or all of the points and you're not that concerned about the actual equation for the regression, then you can break up your data into smooth sections (that doesn't loop back on itself) and fit a polynomial regression to each of these sections individually